# What does "[.s]" mean as in "probe[.s]" type of BPF progs?

Tags: kernel, ebpf, libbpf

In [`BPF Types`](https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/libbpf/program_types.html) it explains to developers about how to understand `type/extras` in libbpf API. As examples, there are such types as fentry and uprobe, types of which are however described to be:

```
uprobe.s+/...
fentry.s+/...
```

In [Footnotes], it uses a `uprobe[.s]` denotation without explain. Is it an part of regular expression or immediate literals to append when I declare using SEC() macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR.** The `.s` part is interpreted literally and means the program is [sleepable](https://lwn.net/Articles/825415/).

---

These section formats are defined in array `section_defs` in libbpf: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.1/source/tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.c#L8894. We can see the two formats for uprobes side-by-side:

```
SEC_DEF("uprobe+",      KPROBE, 0, SEC_NONE, attach_uprobe),
SEC_DEF("uprobe.s+",    KPROBE, 0, SEC_SLEEPABLE, attach_uprobe),
```

The only difference is thus that the .s format is [sleepable](https://lwn.net/Articles/825415/). We can find the same pattern for sleepable uretprobes, multi-uprobes, USDT, LSM, etc.

An example of such program can be found in the BPF selftests: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.1/source/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/progs/test_attach_probe.c#L90.

Comment: Interesting. I've got no idea about this before.